# Convert Tkinter textbox entry into Python Variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

(Long Question)

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will take a file path from the user using a tkinter textbox when a button is pressed. It would then convert that textbox entry to a string attached to a normal python variable so I can use that variable in a function later to use that file. The code I attached can make the label copy the text box entry, but I cannot use that variable or myvar in "normal python code". Also, in the code I tried returning myvar.get() through the function mywarWritten, but I cant set a variable equal to the mywarWritten(parameters) because that is dependent on the textbox entry that doesn't happen until the button is pressed. When the button is pressed the print function works printing the statement but it doesn't return please when the function is set equal to attempt.

(In Short)

I want to take a value, or string, from the user using a Tkinter text box, and use the entry as a normal python variable. Preferably the value in the text box would only be taken when a button is pressed.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.title("MyApp")

myvar = StringVar()

def mywarWritten(*args):
    print "mywarWritten",myvar.get()
    please = myvar.get()
    return please

#trying to make the function return the textbox entry but fails
attempt = mywarWritten()
print "plz %s" % (attempt)

#trying to just set it equal too but also fails
python_variable = myvar.get()
label = Label(root, textvariable=myvar)
label.pack()

text_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=myvar)
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Back to Home", command=lambda: mywarWritten()) 
button1.pack()
text_entry.pack()

#trying attempt and pythonvariable in "normal python code"
print attempt
print pythonvariable
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: function assigned to button can't return value because there is nobody who could receive this variable. Lines `attempt = ...` and `python_variable = ...` are useless because they are executed at start of script when `Entry` is still empy. You have to learn that only code inside functions assigned to `Button` or to other widgets make sense. Everything outside functions is executed only once - at start of script - and is used only to build GUI.

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense. So instead of trying to bring the text entry out, I should bring my function (not shown) inside related to the button correct?

Comment: yes, you have to do everything inside functions.

Comment: Thanks furas I'm looking forward to trying this tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a few misunderstandings about scope, imports, references, and functions. `myvar` is already accessible, and all you have to do to access it is `get()` it. Don't import the same module multiple times, and try to avoid `from x import *`. Returning a value to a button doesn't make any sense and has no effect. Every line of code not in a function or class is executed immediately, so `attempt = mywarWritten()` and all of the other several times you did that outside a function will get the value of that `StringVar` as soon as the program runs, before there's anything in it. And `lambda: func()` is just `func`.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("MyApp")

myvar = tk.StringVar()

def mywarWritten(*args):
    print "mywarWritten", myvar.get()

label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=myvar)
label.pack()

text_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=myvar)
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Back to Home", command=mywarWritten) 
button1.pack()
text_entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Any time you want to access the contents of that entry widget, just do `myvar.get()` and there it will be.

You also have `mywarWritten` instead of `my_var_written`, with a `v` for `var`.

Overall, I very highly recommend you read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html) (and use Python 3, because it's better than Python 2).

Comment: I apologize for the simple errors. I had tried so much stuff it became a mess but I didn't want to delete it or I would've forgotten what I did. I tried clraning it up but clearly overlooked some stuff.