# Is there a way to save the input (float) from a variable created in a user interface in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to make a **user interface** (by using tkinter)in Python that **saves the number you enter**. In this case I want the user to be able to give a start value and an end value of a measurement, which afterwards will be implemented in a code. For this to work, I need the user interface to be able to store the values I enter. However, so far I haven't be able to export my variables with the assigned values. I only managed to get the variables with value 0. 
Could someone please help me figure out my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I used:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text = "Start of measurement (index): ")
tk.Label(root, text = "End of measurement (index): ")

def add_text():
       label1 = tk.Label(root, text="You have entered the start and end index of the measurement")
       label1.pack()



Start = tk.DoubleVar(root)
End = tk.DoubleVar(root)

Start_measurement = Start.get()
End_measurement = End.get()

Start_label = tk.Label(root, text="Start of measurement (index): ")
Start_label.pack()

Start_text_box = tk.Entry(root, bd=1)
Start_text_box.pack()

End_label = tk.Label(root, text="End of measurement (index): ")
End_label.pack()

End_text_box = tk.Entry(root, bd=1)
End_text_box.pack()

enter_button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=add_text)
enter_button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Tkinter textbox entry into Python Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405875/convert-tkinter-textbox-entry-into-python-variable) … *get()* the values in the button's *commad* function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be variable = Start_text_box.get() or variable = End_text_box.get().

Also to close the windows for later use in your code you need to do

```
root.quit()
root.withdraw()
```

For example:

```
def add_text():
    globals()['START']=Start_text_box.get()
    globals()['END']=End_text_box.get()
    print("Start was ", START)
    print("End was ", END)
    root.quit()
    root.withdraw()
```

The globals() is there because the START/END variables are defined within a local function so to use them elsewhere you need to assign them globally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation KJTHoward! I tried it and it worked :-)

Comment: @PallasAthena No problem, happy to help :). Feel free to mark this post as an answer to your question so the question is listed as answered and if anyone else has a similar problem they can find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your `add_text` function you could first get the string of the textbox:

`val1 = Start_text_box.get()`

Then convert it to double:

`val1 = float(val1)`

Then print it

`label1 = tk.Label(root, text="You have entered the start {0} and end index of the measurement".format(val1))`

Comment: Thank you for your advice Toto, the code works now :-)